# laravel 5.2 always redirect to https

Tags: php, laravel

I have trouble with redirect url in laravel. 
I've made the configuration in .env and .htaccess files, but laravel always directs url to https and always return error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. while I develop at http://link.com with virtual host.

```
// .evn
APP_ENV=development
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_KEY=m1FZ2sfRqlooiYEDTYNOaoJnnFmfJj0d
APP_URL=http://link.com/

// .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Web server and database server using MAMP PRO.
help me please

Comment: 1) when developing you shouldn't use hostnames that may exist and you don't own 2) are you sure it's laravel and not the browser?

Comment: Can I see your Vhost configuration ?

Comment: in mamp pro i just create domain and automatic configuring. in folder `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` no configuration just `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca not browser problem. this laravel. in index.php i just run code after `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);` with `var_dump($kernel)` url still http. after this code `$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);` then changed https